# "Update model from Database" adding a table without a key

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have a collection of entities that I generated from a database. One table will not add to the EDMX file because it does not have a key or even something that can automatically be inferred as a key.

Redesigning the DB table is not possible. Is there a way to add this table to my diagram?

I remember a simple technique a while back but the details ahve escaped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to take you at your word that you can not change the table, and still ask you to please try to do that :) just because how bad of an idea this is.  But assuming that you can not do anything about that after trying for the nth time try this post and see if it helps:
http://www.benhblog.com/2008/11/entity-framework-and-tables-with-no.html

Comment: Oh believe me I would love to change the table. But it is part of a Enterprise Management System that I am stuck with for the next few years. It's obivious that the company that wrote this never employeed a DBA or even someone with an ounce of DB experience.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this blog entry which was a bit more descriptive:
http://pratapreddypilaka.blogspot.in/2012/04/entity-framework-adding-datatable-with.html

Since my model is completely read-only it worked fairly well.